# emacs/gdb: show sources of shared objects

Tags: object, emacs, gdb, shared, gud

I have a problem with debugging C++ with emacs and gdb. I can set breakpoints in functions defined in shared objects by simply adding them manually via

```
b file_in_so.cpp:23
```

But if I open file_in_so.cpp in an emacs window I cannot set the breakpoints via mouse. Emacs simply does not yet know that this source files belongs to the list of source files. This also happens if the gdb already runs and waits in another breakpoint. Is there a command telling emacs to reload the current list of all sources, even the ones defined in shared objects?